# How to run spring boot admin client and server in same application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I want to run a spring boot admin server and client inside the same application.I changed server port, when I change the server port spring admin will access my changed port. so I can run an admin server. but I can't see my web application pages.

i need output like this.

Localhost:8080/myapplication (my client application)
localhost:8090/admin (spring boot admin server)

Comment: Is it one application or 2 application

Comment: Ammar ali ,inside one application, admin and client separate using port.

Comment: which spring boot version you are using

Comment: im using spring boot 2.0.4.RELEASE  
and spring boot admin 2.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to run the application on two different ports for admin client and for server client.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder parentBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
    parentBuilder.child(ServiceOneConfiguration.class).properties("server.port:8081").run(args);
    parentBuilder.child(ServiceTwoConfiguration.class).properties("server.port:8082").run(args);
}

@Service
static class SharedService {
    public String getMessage(String name) {
        return String.format("Hello, %s, I'm shared service", name);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
static class ServiceOneConfiguration {
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/server")
    static class ControllerOne {
        @Autowired
        private SharedService service;

        @RequestMapping(produces = "text/plain;charset=utf-8")
        @ResponseBody
        public String getMessage(String name) {
            return "ControllerOne says \"" + service.getMessage(name) + "\"";
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
static class ServiceTwoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        tomcat.setUriEncoding("cp1251");
        return tomcat;
    }

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/client")
    static class ControllerTwo {
        @Autowired
        private SharedService service;

        @RequestMapping(produces = "text/plain;charset=utf-8")
        @ResponseBody
        public String getMessage(String name) {
            return "ControllerTwo says \"" + service.getMessage(name) + "\"";
        }
    }
}
}
```

For more detail here is a link:
[spring-boot-connectors](https://github.com/dddpaul/spring-boot-connectors)
Hope this will help.

Comment: Read this migration guide https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#embedded-containers-package-structure

Comment: Try to change port

Comment: according to error another application is using same port. change the port then it'll work

Comment: that's good it's finally working. Mark this answer as correct so that others will take advantage.

Answer (score 0):

we can use spring boot multi modules like following.

```
main app
    spring-boot-admin
    pom.xml ( running port 8888 )
    my project
    pom.xml ( running port 8080 )
pom.xml
```